# Connection timeout and reconnection in Swift

Tags: swift, nsurlconnection, connection-timeout

I wrote the following function to establish the synchronous connection with server, send request and receive the response, which works properly.

```
func connserv()
{
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://144.1.1.45:8000")!)
    //request.timeoutInterval = 10 // for implementing timeout
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    var response: NSURLResponse?
    var error: NSError?
    println("Firing synchronous url connection......")
    let urlData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &error)

    if urlData == nil
    {
         println("Error happend timeout======\(error)!")
    }
    else
    {
        println("\(urlData!.length) bytes of data was returned")
        println(response!);
        println(NSString(data: urlData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    }


}
```

Yesterday I added the following line of code to implement **connection timeout**, which works properly yesterday but it is not working today. I do not know what went wrong.

```
request.timeoutInterval = 10
```

**Can you please tell me how can I implement the connection timeout in the above function and this function should also try to reconnect the server three times.**

[image]

Comment: Your code works, it timeouts after 10 secs, I just ran a test (see [screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s236/sh/60d1164e-b66a-4b93-a95c-3ffbfae69e4f/e9bba8efa4165524900dbc9076d2c72b)). You just have to manage the reconnect in `if urlData == nil`.

Comment: Thanks Eric D, I agree with you, this function worked properly yesterday, but it does not work today. I have also added screen shot for this.

Comment: Wow. Look at [this](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s236/sh/7544ac72-17ec-4109-955f-466401ef734b/f6e6a740200b8d7cb5efc302a90e8135), using the same code as you *and the same URL*, it works ok for me. So, yes, *the code works* (since it works for me with your URL, and the code is straightforward enough to be guaranteed working), your problem is elsewhere (and I have no idea where).

Comment: Why don't you show us Error domain, code and description?

Comment: Satachito,                                                                                                                           Error happend timeout======Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo=0x7bfbfb10 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://144.1.1.45:8000, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://144.1.1.45:8000, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, NSUnderlyingError=0x7bfbf210 "Could not connect to the server."})!

Comment: Is your question is 'How to implement reconnection?

Comment: Yes, I will look into reconnection implementation later, but code is not waiting for timeout interval is my issue right now.

Comment: The same code was working properly yesterday in respect to timeout interval.

Comment: Try 'curl -v https://144.1.1.45:8000 --max-time 5'

Comment: The error code -1004 doesn't mean timeout. It shows 'Could not connect to the server' as described.

Comment: So check your route to the server.

Comment: Actually its a matter of router. I am using two routers.